# How to override methods of ExtJS component?

Tags: extjs4

While working with ExtJS, sometimes I needed to override methods of components.

For example, there is one method `createPicker` in `Ext.form.field.ComboBox`. I want to write my own logic for that method. How can I do? Is `Ext.override` useful here? as I never use it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a define statement. This gives you an advantage of being able to hook it into the class system, so it can be required:

```
Ext.define('MyOverrideName', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',

    createPicker: function() {
        console.log('I am an override!');
        // Will call Ext.form.field.ComboBox.createPicker, the thing we're overriding
        // this.callParent(); 
        // Will call Ext.form.field.Picker.createPicker, the superclass of combo
        // this.callSuper();
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi.. @Evan Trimboli thanks.. I am doing the same using extend keyword instead of overriding in your example. Is there any difference in that?

Comment: Yes. `extend` creates a whole new class. `override` changes the method directly on the class.

Comment: I always do it using: `Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Combobox, {` Is this just another way to do what you have shown above?